# Javascript run function as soon as data updates?

Tags: javascript, promise, listener, es6-promise, setinterval

So when my web application opens, component A makes an api call the result of which it stores in some place. There is another javascript component B which needs the value of that variable. How can B access the variable as soon as the data gets updated. Currently, I had to resort to adding setInterval function in B to continously listen for variable value changes but I was hoping for a better solution. Will promises help in some way? Any help would be appreciated.
Note: Component A and component B are not connected. No way for component A to call methods/data of component B and hence had to keep data in a third place.

Comment: Some kind of event listener solution could work. E.g. pubsub.

Comment: they doesnt' have any connection? what they are? Modules that are imported? They are stored on window/global? more information is needed.

Comment: If they run on the same Browser window, they can have an connection, the question is, how is your application organized, to use the best connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can make B call the A method and wait for it to end.

```js
await A()

async function A(){
// ...things
    return data
}
```

You can also work with events, in a way that B pass an callback function to A, that registers and call it when it's done.

```js
let callback = null

function AReady(cb){ callback =  cb } 

async function A(){
// ...things
     if(callback) callback(data)
}
```

If they doesn't have any connection at all, you will need to make one. If they are modules, you can export `AReady`. If they are on window, you will need to set `window.AReady = AReady`, epxosing the method (also, B need to be loaded after A, or wait for `document.ready`)

Comment: From OP: *"Component A and component B are not connected. No way for component A to call methods/data of component B and hence had to keep data in a third place."*

Comment: @FelixKling I don't get it

Comment: You are saying that B should call A but the OP says that there is no connection between those components, so presumably that doesn't  work.

Comment: @FelixKling What is OP and why it doesn't Work? What is wrong?

Comment: OP stands for *"original post"* or *"original poster"*. I'm just referring to the information that is contained in the question.

Comment: OH sorry ok. Odd question, i will ask for more information, but probably this answer will fit with editing

Comment: Fixed, showing ways to create an connection to the modules.

Answer (score 0):

Some kind of global notification system would work. There are popular third party packages that you can use, such as [pubsub-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pubsub-js), but you could also implement a simple version yourself.

Here is an example of how it would work:

```
// Inside component B

// at startup
PubSub.subscribe('data from A', function(_, data) {
  // do stuff with data
});
```

```
// Inside component A

// load data, then
Pubsub.publish('data from A', data);
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, promises can help, just use async/await in both components.